# Problems defining an ANTLR parser for template file

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have started working with ANTLR4 to create a syntax parser for a self defined template file format.

The format basically consists of a mandatory part called '#settings' and at least one part called '#region'. Parts body is surrounded by braces.

I have created a sample file and also copy-pasted-modified an antlr g4 file to parse it. Works fine so far:

File:

```
#settings
{
setting1: value1
setting2: value2
}

#region
{
[Key1]=Value1(Comment1)
[Key2]=Value2(Comment2)
}
```

The G4 file for this sample:

```
grammar Template;

start
    : section EOF
    ;

section
    : settings regions
    ;

settings
    : '#settings' '{' (settingsText)* '}'
    ;

settingsText
    : TEXT
    ;

regions
    : (region)+
    ;

region
    : '#region' '{' (regionText)* '}'
    ;

regionName
    : NOSPACE
    ;

regionText
    : TEXT
    ;

TEXT
    : (~[\u0000-\u001F])+
    ;

NOSPACE
    : (~[\u0000-\u0020])+
    ;

WS
   : [ \t\n\r] + -> skip
   ;
```

This works as expected. Now I want to add complexity to the file format and the parser and extend the #region header by #region NAME (Attributes).
So what I changed in the sample and in the G4 file is:

Sample changed to

```
...
#region name (attributes, moreAttributes)
{
...
```

and g4 file modified to

```
grammar Template;

start
    : section EOF
    ;

section
    : settings regions
    ;

settings
    : '#settings' '{' (settingsText)* '}'
    ;

settingsText
    : TEXT
    ;

regions
    : (region)+
    ;

region
    : '#region' regionName (regionAttributes)? '{' (regionText)* '}'
    ;

regionName
    : NOSPACE
    ;

regionAttributes
    : '(' regionAttribute (',' regionAttribute)* ')'
    ;

regionAttribute
    : NOSPACE
    ;

regionText
    : TEXT
    ;

TEXT
    : (~[\u0000-\u001F])+
    ;

NOSPACE
    : (~[\u0000-\u0020])+
    ;

WS
   : [ \t\n\r] + -> skip
   ;
```

Now the parser brings up the following error:
**Parser error (7, 1): mismatched input '#region name (attributes, moreAttributes)' expecting '#region'**

And I don't get why it is behaving like this. I expected the parser to not concat the whole line when comparing. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here:

1. whatever `NOSPACE` matches, is also matched by `TEXT`
2. `TEXT` is waaaaay too greedy

### Issue 1

ANTLR's lexer works independently from the parser and the lexer will match as much characters as possible.

When 2 (or more) lexer rules match the same amount of characters, the one defined first "wins".

So, if the input is `Foo` and the parser is. trying to match a `NOSPACE` token, you're out of luck: because both `TEXT` and `NOSPACE` match the text `Foo` and `TEXT` is defined first, the lexer will produce a `TEXT` token. There's nothing you can do about that: it's the way ANTLR works.

### Issue 2

As explained in issue 1, the lexer tries to match as much characters as possible. Because of that, your `TEXT` rule is too greedy. This is what your input is tokenised as:

```
'{'                  `{`
TEXT                 `setting1: value1`
TEXT                 `setting2: value2`
'}'                  `}`
TEXT                 `#region name (attributes, moreAttributes)`
'{'                  `{`
TEXT                 `[Key1]=Value1(Comment1)`
TEXT                 `[Key2]=Value2(Comment2)`
'}'                  `}`
```

As you can see, `TEXT` matches too much. And this is what the error

> Parser error (7, 1): mismatched input '#region name (attributes, moreAttributes)' expecting '#region'

is telling you: `#region name (attributes, moreAttributes)` is a single `TEXT` token where a `#region` is trying to be matched by the parser.

### Solution?

Remove `NOSPACE` and make the `TEXT` token less greedy (or the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

Bart,

thank you very much for clarifying this to me. The key phrase was *the lexer will match as much characters as possible*. This is a behavior I still need to get used to. I redesigned my Lexer and Parser rules and it seems to work for my test case now.

For completeness, this is my g4 File now:

```
grammar Template;

start
    : section EOF
    ;

section
    : settings regions
    ;

settings
    : '#settings' '{' (settingsText)* '}'
    ;

regions
    : (region)+
    ;

region
    : '#region' regionName (regionAttributes)? '{' (regionText)* '}'
    ;

regionName
    : TEXT
    ;

settingsText
    : TEXT
    ;

regionAttributes
    : '(' regionAttribute (',' regionAttribute)* ')'
    ;

regionAttribute
    : TEXT
    ;

regionText
    : regionLine '('? (regionComment?) ')'?
    ;

regionLine
    : TEXT
    ;

regionComment
    : TEXT
    ;

TEXT
    : ([A-z0-9:\-|= ])+
    ;

WS
   : [ \t\n\r] + -> skip
   ;
```